# two buttons conflicting in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have two buttons that are divs and two paragraph, they each match up to each other.  So you click button one, button one rotates 45 degrees and toggleslides paragraph one open, button two does the same except for paragraph two.  For some reason though if you click the first button it opens both paragraphs, and if you click button two nothing happens, and I can't figure out why.  I'm going to need to set up multiple buttons and paragraphs eventually.

```
var epidural_analgesia_INFO = document.images[0];
epidural_analgesia_INFO.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition", "-webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out");

var epidural_analgesia_DEG = 0;

epidural_analgesia_INFO.addEventListener('click', function() {
$("p#epidural_analgesia_TEXT").slideToggle("fast");
epidural_analgesia_DEG += 45;
epidural_analgesia_INFO.style.setProperty('-webkit-transform', 'rotateZ('+epidural_analgesia_DEG+'deg)');   
});




var effects_of_yoga_INFO = document.images[0];
effects_of_yoga_INFO.style.setProperty("-webkit-transition", "-webkit-transform 0.3s ease-in-out");

var effects_of_yoga_DEG = 0;

effects_of_yoga_INFO.addEventListener('click', function() {
$("p#effects_of_yoga_TEXT").slideToggle("fast");
effects_of_yoga_DEG += 45;
effects_of_yoga_INFO.style.setProperty('-webkit-transform', 'rotateZ('+effects_of_yoga_DEG+'deg)');   
});
```

I have a fiddle setup, but it's large and so I've pulled out the specific parts here, but if you want to see teh fiddle it's here: http://jsfiddle.net/loriensleafs/AM2a2/12/  thanks very much for helping me.

Answer (score 2):

You're assigning your click handlers to the elements referenced by these two variables:

```
epidural_analgesia_INFO
effects_of_yoga_INFO
```

but both variables are initialised to reference `document.images[0]`. So clicking that image triggers both handlers. Should the second one perhaps use an index of `1` to get the second image?

(As an aside, why use `addEventListener()` when you seem to be using jQuery?)

Comment: how would you set that up using jquery, I wasn't sure how to do it

Comment: set up the event listener w/ jquery, how would you re write that function?

Comment: To assign a click handler to an element with the id `"epidural_analgesia_INFO"` you'd say `$("#epidural_analgesia_INFO").click(function() { ... });` or `$("#epidural_analgesia_INFO").on("click", function() { ... });` (jQuery will then take care of the cross-browser stuff you need to have the event handler work with, e.g., older versions of IE.)

Answer (score 0):

got it, in teh first line

var epidural_analgesia_INFO = document.getElementById('epidural_analgesia_INFO');

instead of

var effects_of_yoga_INFO = document.images[0];